# Contains method doesn't seem to work with a point inside my polygon

Tags: java, 2d, awt, polygon

I am trying to add a functionnality which would let me see if a point is inside a polygon.

Here's the code snippet to see if the point is inside my polygon

```
int x = 265;
int y = 300;
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>(); 

points.add(new Point(233,155));
points.add(new Point(347,269));
points.add(new Point(136,251));
points.add(new Point(250,366));

Polygon polygon = new Polygon();//java.awt.Polygon

for(Point point : points) {
    polygon.addPoint(point.x, point.y);
}

return polygon.contains(x,y);
```

The code seems to work if my point is closer to the upper-left side of the polygon, however when the point is on the bottom-right side, the method contains will return false.

Graph of my polygon and the point in question : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tnglrdpivn

Any idea why this happens ?

Comment: In order for us to help, what are the `points` and what are `x` & `y` that reproduce the issue you're having? Also make sure you read thru the [definition of insideness](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#def_insideness) for this implementation.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @Krease as you have requested I've added more info to make my question clearer, thanks for your input.

Comment: Much clearer now - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is in the ordering of your points. Though plotted all at once on a graph, they look like they form a nice looking polygon, if you play connect-the-dots with them in the order you add them to the polygon, they form a very weird shape, and the point is really not contained in the polygon.

If you reverse the order of your last two points, the connect-the-dots polygon is properly formed, and then the point *is* contained in the polygon.